# 404 error when uploading pdf as content topic using valence API

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I've been trying to upload a file to D2L via their valence API, and have been getting a 404 error every time. This is the request that is being sent with a standard REST client:

Route:

```
POST /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/content/modules/(moduleId)/structure/
```

Headers:

```
{Content-Length=394, Content-Type=multipart/mixed; boundary=xxBOUNDARYxx}
```

Post body:

```
--xxBOUNDARYxx
Content-Type: application/json

{"Title":"Syllabus","ShortTitle":"test","Type":1,"TopicType":1,"Url":"/content/enforced2/2163764-ENGR_059009_SEC001_20133/test.txt","EndDate":null,"StartDate":null,"DueDate":null,"IsHidden":false,"IsLocked":false}
--xxBOUNDARYxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="text.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

some test file
--xxBOUNDARYxx--
```

We aren't getting any invalid token errors, just a blank 404 Not Found. Could someone help explain why this request isn't going through? We are hoping to build a more complicated request, but cannot get this basic one to be functional first.

Comment: Which API route are you trying to use?

Comment: @JacobParker The route I'm using is: 
POST /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/content/modules/(moduleId)/structure/

Comment: are you using \r\n for the newlines after the boundary/headers? If you have a Fiddler dump of your exact request I could use that to debug further.